# Adding validation on fields to make sure user does not submitted the form empty

Tags: angular, forms, validation, edit

I need to add validation to angular form to make sure user does not submitted the form empty for editing operation , I did not use formBuilder , and I hope find solution without formBuilder or formgroup .
my html code is :

```
<div class="container p-0">
 <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="card" *ngIf="currentForm">
           <h4 class="card-header"> Edit Subscriber </h4>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="addForm">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subscriberName">Subscriber Name</label>
                            <input type="text" id="subscriberName"  #subscriberName="ngModel" name="subscriberName"  [(ngModel)]="currentForm.subscribers.subscriber[0].subscriberName" class="form-control" required minlength="1" maxlength="100">
                            <div [hidden]="subscriberName.valid || subscriberName.pristine"
                            class="alert alert-danger"> Name is required</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="button">
                        <button type="submit" routerLink="/viewsubscriber" class="btn btn-primary (click)="onSubmit()">Update</button> </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my ts code :

```
   onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
      let requestBody={subscriberName: this.currentForm.subscribers.subscriber[0].subscriberName }
      console.log(requestBody); 
    this.userService.editSubscriber(this.currentForm.subscribers.subscriber[0].subscriberId,requestBody)
      .subscribe(
        _response =>  {  const confirmDialog = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
          data: {
            title: 'info',
            message: 'subscriber edited successfuly ' 
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put an `if` condition in your `onSubmit` method on top.

```
    onSubmit() {
        if (!this.currentForm.subscribers.subscriber[0].subscriberName) {
            console.log('name required');
            return false;
            }
            this.submitted = true;
              let requestBody={subscriberName: this.currentForm.subscribers.subscriber[0].subscriberName }
              console.log(requestBody); 
            this.userService.editSubscriber(this.currentForm.subscribers.subscriber[0].subscriberId,requestBody)
              .subscribe(
                _response =>  {  const confirmDialog = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
                  data: {
                    title: 'info',
                    message: 'subscriber edited successfuly ' 
                  }
                });
               }
```

Comment: it is return to previous page when I submit the button I need to stop the process in form page until user fill the fields

Comment: just remove `routerLink="/viewsubscriber"` from your button html code and if routing is neccessary then route throught `ts` code after successfull response from service in subscribed method.

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If your form has required controls, then you can use `valid` property of the form to check if everything is correct. Add `[disabled]="!currentForm.valid"` on your submit button as shown below:

```
<button routerLink="/viewsubscriber" class="btn btn-primary [disabled]="!currentForm.valid">
    Update
</button>
```

Also, put `[formGroup]="currentForm"` and `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"` on the `<form>` tag and remove the `(click)` event from your submit button.

Comment: thanx faisal, but [formGroup]="currentForm" does not work correctly with me so I avoid to use it , I just need to validate fields

Comment: In that case just add `[disabled]="!currentForm.valid"`

Comment: yes  after I add it , button became not active , so I could not click it